# "'HttpRequestMessageProperties' does not contain a definition for 'PathHandler'" despite using System.Web.Odata.Extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently learning how to create OData services with [MS's ASP.NET web API guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4) . In the Helpers section, trying to grab the field `HttpRequestMessage.ODataProperties().PathHandler` or `...Model` throws the above error. According to [MS's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.extensions.httprequestmessageproperties(v=vs.118).aspx), the import System.Web.OData.Extensions should be right.

Working with 6.13.0 for Odata.Client and 7.0.0 for Odata.Core.

Relevant code, basically 1:1 with the web api guide:

```
using Microsoft.OData;
using Microsoft.OData.UriParser;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Routing;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;

namespace WebApiGuide {
public static class Helpers
{
    public static TKey GetKeyFromUri<TKey>(HttpRequestMessage Request, Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
        }

        var urlHelper = Request.GetUrlHelper() ?? new UrlHelper(Request);

        string serviceRoot = urlHelper.CreateODataLink(
            Request.ODataProperties().RouteName,
            Request.ODataProperties().PathHandler, new List<ODataPathSegment>());
        var odataPath = Request.ODataProperties().PathHandler.Parse(
            Request.ODataProperties().Model,
            serviceRoot, uri.LocalPath);

        var keySegment = odataPath.Segments.OfType<KeyValuePathSegment>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (keySegment == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The link does not contain a key");
        }

        var value = ODataUriUtils.ConvertFromUriLiteral(keySegment.Value, ODataVersion.V4);
        return (TKey)value;
    }
}
}
```

Edit: If it makes the issue any more specific, I have the same issue with `KeyValuePathSegment` which is in `System.Web.OData.Routing`

Comment: Show the relevant part of your code

Comment: I've updated the post to include it.

Comment: @SamJackSon link is dead

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else ending up here for the same reasons I did, here's my code (apparently `keySegment` also changed and the `Value` contains the already converted object):

```
public static TKey GetKeyFromUri<TKey>(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri uri)
{
    if (uri == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));
    }

    var urlHelper = request.GetUrlHelper() ?? new UrlHelper(request);
    var serviceRoot = urlHelper.CreateODataLink(request.ODataProperties().RouteName, request.GetPathHandler(), new List<ODataPathSegment>());
    var odataPath = request.GetPathHandler().Parse(serviceRoot, uri.LocalPath, request.GetRequestContainer());

    var keySegment = odataPath.Segments.OfType<KeySegment>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (keySegment?.Keys?.FirstOrDefault() == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The link does not contain a key.");
    }

    return (TKey)keySegment.Keys.First().Value;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this with .NET core 2.2 https://stackoverflow.com/q/55046209/196526

Comment: Funny thing, I opened an older .NET core project which I remembered I used to try working with OData and .NET core and I found a commented piece of code trying to do this. So I tried, failed and gave up.
I don't have time right now to try but I found an answer that might help, it appears there's an ODataRoute attribute that does this automatically.
Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/54111132/1187199

Comment: I just realized I work with a Microsoft.AspNet.OData.ODataController. This one is a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase. In Controller base I don't have a HttpRequestMessage but a HttpRequest. So I need to adapt more code.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but you can use the `GetPathHandler()` extension method on the `HttpRequestMessage` class. So instead of `Request.ODataProperties().PathHandler`, you can use `Request.GetPathHandler()`.

I hope this helps someone else with this problem.

Comment: By adding which reference ? I'm using .NET Core 2.2

Answer (score 0):

In case you use the `Microsoft.AspNet.OData.ODataController`. The `ODataController` inherits from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`. In this base controller class you cannot find a `HttpRequestMessage` but a `HttpRequest`. So you need to adapt more code:

```
    public static Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataPath CreateODataPath(this HttpRequest request, Uri uri)
    {
        var pathHandler = request.GetPathHandler();
        var serviceRoot = request.GetUrlHelper().CreateODataLink(
                                request.ODataFeature().RouteName,
                                pathHandler,
                                new List<ODataPathSegment>());

        return pathHandler.Parse(serviceRoot, uri.LocalPath, request.GetRequestContainer());
    }

    public static TKey GetKeyValue<TKey>(this HttpRequest request, Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
        }

        //get the odata path Ex: ~/entityset/key/$links/navigation
        var odataPath = request.CreateODataPath(uri);
        var keySegment = odataPath.Segments.OfType<KeySegment>().LastOrDefault();
        if (keySegment == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This link does not contain a key.");
        }

        return (TKey)keySegment.Keys.First().Value;
    }
```

Part of this code come from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54111132/196526 where you can get more information. Maybe.